# Filtering a numeric column name in SAS SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, sas

I was trying to select a reporting month column from table temp_trans, it looks like:

```
GPNr  202112 202201 202202 .... 202208
x     1      5      2      .... 3
y     0.4    2      3      .... 8
z     3      1      5      .... 6



proc sql noprint;
  select distinct Berichtsmonat into :timeperiod1 - FROM work.Basis;

quit;

%put & timeperiod1
```

---> 202112

Now I was trying to apply a condition on the 202112 column:

Code:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_TEMP_TRANS_0000 AS
   SELECT t1.*
      FROM WORK.TEMP_TRANS t1
      WHERE t1.&timeperiod1 NOT = .;
QUIT;
```

I get following a synthax error message for t1.202112 .
It runs when I make out of it : where t1.'202112'n not = .;

Any clue how I can get fixed this?
Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Ben

Comment: Why (and how) did you end up with non-standard variable names to begin with?  If you set the validvarname option to V7 then SAS will not let you use values that start with digits as the name of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Put the macro-variable inside **double** quotes and add a trailing `n` to use the name literal syntax.
Single quotes won't resolve macro-variables inside of them, double will.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
    select t1.*
    from have t1
    where t1."&timeperiod."n ne .;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change how you create the macro variable, so it's a valid SAS variable name.
Use the NLITERAL function.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select distinct nliteral(Berichtsmonat) into :timeperiod1 - FROM work.Basis;

quit;

%put & timeperiod1.;

PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_TEMP_TRANS_0000 AS
   SELECT t1.*
      FROM WORK.TEMP_TRANS t1
      WHERE t1.&timeperiod1 NOT = .;
QUIT;
```